# Why does not the 'outer' function work properly for some argument values in R?

Tags: r

When I run the R command:

```
 outer(37:42, 37:42, complex, 1)
```

I get an error

> "Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : dims [product 36] do not match the length of object [37]"

in my R session. But when I run

```
outer(36:42, 36:42, complex, 1)
```

I have a valid matrix as a result. The problem persists for all values greater than 36. And there is no problem for all values less then 37.

Is this a bug?

**My system**: Microsoft R Open 3.4.4 / RStudio 1.1.447 / Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It seems that there is a rule: the error appeares if the difference between upper and lower values in both vectors is less than 6: >outer(39:45, 39:45, complex, 1) - do work; >outer(39:44, 39:44, complex, 1) - does not.

Comment: `outer(37:42, 37:42, complex, length.out=0)` this works, not just 0 but any value , it will work till it can recycle, This problem is also disscuess in r-inferno , You can read about it , with functions like max to make it vectorize to use it. However, I am puzzled to see why complex on/off behavior is there. http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno_090109.pdf

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, when running the function with arguments `m:n`, `m:n` it returns the error whenever `n < (n - m + 1)^2` <sup>[citation needed]</sup>. Try for example `outer(20:23, 20:23, complex, 1)` and `outer(20:24, 20:24, complex, 1)`, where the first will fail but the latter won't, because `24 < (24-20+1)^2`. I suspect this has to do with the first argument of `complex` being `length.out`, which defines the `length` of the vector to return - not really an explanation, I know. So your first argument `37:42` is passed to the `length.out` parameter. This does not make a lot of sense so please correct me if I am wrong, but I think what you want to do is the following:

```
outer(37:42, 37:42, function(x,y) {complex(1, real = x, imaginary = y)})
```

Which outputs:

```
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] 37+37i 37+38i 37+39i 37+40i 37+41i 37+42i
[2,] 38+37i 38+38i 38+39i 38+40i 38+41i 38+42i
[3,] 39+37i 39+38i 39+39i 39+40i 39+41i 39+42i
[4,] 40+37i 40+38i 40+39i 40+40i 40+41i 40+42i
[5,] 41+37i 41+38i 41+39i 41+40i 41+41i 41+42i
[6,] 42+37i 42+38i 42+39i 42+40i 42+41i 42+42i
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or just `outer(37:42, 37:42, complex, length.out = 1)`. I admit I don't understand what `complex` is doing with the vector input `outer` is passing to `length.out` in OP's code.

Comment: I suspect it tries to fill the entire matrix or something, because it seems to run into errors whenever the `lenght` of the vector is longer than the amount of elements in the matrix. And yes, the `outer` statement can be a bit shorter but since the confusion is caused by the wrong values being passed to the wrong parameters, I think it makes sense to type them out in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the 4th argument: it should be named:

> outer(37:42, 37:42, complex, length.out = 1)

works fine!